# How to capture MOUSE_WHEELED event?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-console

When using [ReadConsoleInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961(v=vs.85).aspx) to get [INPUT_RECORD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683499(v=vs.85).aspx) events I can't seem to get any [MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684239(v=vs.85).aspx) events with the flag MOUSE_WHEELED set.

It seems the console captures the mouse wheel for the consoles own scroll bar.

I do get the desired behaviour if I set "Use legacy console" but this is a global setting are there does not appear to be an api set change it.

How do I get the console to pass through the MOUSE_WHEELED events?

Comment: Since it works in a "legacy" console, it stands to reason that this is probably a legacy feature that is not meant to work in a modern console anymore. You may have to resort to a mouse hook using `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `RegisterRawInputDevices()` instead.

Comment: You probably have to call SetConsoleScreenBufferSize() to make the screen buffer the same size as the window.  Quickest way to check this is by using the system menu > Properties > Layout tab > Screen buffer size settings.

Comment: I have tried setting the buffer size to the same as the window. Still do not receive the mouse wheeled message.